# How to download Sitecore Images

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

```
var database = Database.GetDatabase(“master”);
var images = database.SelectItems(“/sitecore/media library/your image folder/descendant::*[@@templatekey=’jpeg’]”);

foreach (var image in images)
{
var mediaItem = (MediaItem)image;
var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
var stream = media.GetStream();

using (var targetStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(“your data path”, image.Name + “.jpeg” )))
{
stream.CopyTo(targetStream);
targetStream.Flush();
}
}
```

I'm new to Sitecore, can anyone help me in how to download images from Sitecore to the local folder in our PC and when I searched I found a code but not working. The error is Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Images\RedTorch.jpeg'

Comment: What code are you using? What happens when it 'doesn't work'? We need this information to provide an answer. In particular we need to know what behaviour you're expecting and what actually happens (error code, incorrect output etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice blog post describing how to download images from particular folder in media library: [Save all images of a media library folder to disk](http://learningsitecore.com/2013/07/17/save-all-images-of-a-media-library-folder-to-disk-2/).

**IMPORTANT**: remember that user which is used by the IIS process must have write access to the `c:\tmp` directory (or any other directory you use).

And the code from there:

```cs
var database = Database.GetDatabase("master");
var images = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/media library/your image folder/descendant::*[@@templatekey='jpeg']");

foreach (var image in images)
{
    var mediaItem = (MediaItem)image;
    var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
    var stream = media.GetStream();

    using (var targetStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("c:\\tmp", image.Name + ".jpeg" )))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(targetStream);
        targetStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

From your comments it looks like instead of saving media items on the server hard drive, you want to download them to the computer which is used to browse the site. Is that correct?

In that scenario, you can use code below. It will generate a zip of all media items which are direct children on the selected folder and allow user to download this zip:

```cs
string tempFolderPath = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.TempFolderPath;
tempFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(tempFolderPath);
string zipName = "media" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".zip";
ZipWriter zipWriter = new ZipWriter(Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, zipName));

var database = Database.GetDatabase("master");
var images = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/media library/your folder/*");

foreach (var image in images)
{
    if (MediaManager.HasMediaContent(image))
    {
        var mediaItem = (MediaItem) image;
        var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
        var stream = media.GetStream();

        zipWriter.AddEntry(mediaItem.Name + "." + mediaItem.Extension, stream.Stream);
    }
}

zipWriter.Dispose();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline;filename=\"{0}\"", zipName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, zipName)))
{
    sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Tq, I have tried this and it is working fine until getstream() method. when I,m trying to write it is not writing to the local folder

Comment: what do you mean by IIS process permissions @Marek Musielak

Comment: Yes. Check the app pool which is used by this web application and see what identity it uses. Then check it's access rights to that folder.

Comment: Does this error "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Images\RedTorch.jpeg" is this anyway related to app pool

Comment: It is downloading as a zip but cannot able to open it. It is showing "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged".

Comment: I'm sorry its working perfectly alright, tq very much -  Marek Musielak

Answer (score 0):

The code from your example looks okay and is roughly the same as Marek's answer, what might be the problem here is that you are using Path.Combine to include a new folder that probably does not exist yet (based on the error message you get: "Could not find a part of the path").

If you will add this line just before writing to the file (create a variable first, holding your final and complete path string), you can be sure that all directories exist before writing the file to disk:

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
```

Comment: Then this was not the issue, but could be. Anyway this line is always safe to include to ensure the path exists. Does the update of Mareks post help you out?

Comment: @SrinuA : I now see you wrote "on my local disk". I assume you are running your site locally as well? If not, you are downloading this image on the server and not on your local machine and that is why you get the message: the directory on the server doesn't exists. You would prevent that from happening if you would implement this line of code.

But I guess you do want to download it locally and not to the server, so you're on the wrong track with the example code in your OP. If so Marek's updates answer solves your problem. Please let us know what worked for you.

Comment: Tq for all of your support,its not working either way.